# MS Office Files are not recognized by comparing signatures

Tags: c++, file

I need to check that whether a file is `.doc`, `.ppt`, `.pdf` or any other. I have written the following code:

```
bool CheckFile(string path)
{
    char * sig;
    sig = new char[8];
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(path.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (myfile.fail())
    {
        MessageBox(0,"File Not Opened","ERROR",MB_OK);
        break;
    }
    myfile.read(sig,8);

    //docx, pptx, xlsx
    if ((sig[0] == (0x50))&&(sig[1] == (0x4B))&&(sig[2] == (0x03))&&(sig[3] == (0x04))&&(sig[4] == (0x14))&&(sig[5] == (0x00))&&(sig[6] == (0x06))&&(sig[7] == (0x00)))
    {
        return true;
    }

    //doc, ppt, xls
    if ((sig[0] == (0xD0))&&(sig[1] == (0xCF))&&(sig[2] == (0x11))&&(sig[3] == (0xE0))&&(sig[4] == (0xA1))&&(sig[5] == (0xB1))&&(sig[6] == (0x1A))&&(sig[7] == (0xE1)))
    {
        return true;
    }

    //pdf
    if ((sig[0] == (0x25))&&(sig[1] == (0x50))&&(sig[2] == (0x44))&&(sig[3] == (0x46)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    delete sig;
    myfile.close();
    return false;
}
```

I looked up on the internet and found that we can compare the signatures, i.e. first 8 bytes in case of MS office files and first 4 bytes in case `PDFs`. In the code above, I am doing the same. `CheckFile()` returns `TRUE` in case of `PDFs` and Office 2007 formats including `.docx` and `.pptx` but returns `FALSE` in case of `.doc` and `.ppt`. The console output for the a `.doc` file is:

```
FFFFFFD0
FFFFFFCF
11
FFFFFFE0
FFFFFFA1
FFFFFFB1
1A
FFFFFFE1
```

Where each line corresponds to hex of char in sig. Note that the last byte is the same as the signature of `.doc` file. I don't know why these extra `FFFFFF` are present here. What could be the problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the problem with `FFFFFFFF`, you might notice that the last byte of those numbers are larger than `0x7f` which means that they, for a signed byte is negative. So you are using a signed `char` and the compiler sign-extends it when you print the values.

You should change to `unsigned char` (or even better, the standard type `uint8_t`).

Comment: I have tried to use `unsigned char*` instead of `char*` but `myfile.read()` gives error. It does not accept `unsigned char*`.

Comment: @Faheem Cast it in the `read` function: `myfile.read(static_cast<char*>(sig), 8);`

Comment: Casting works simply by `myfile.read((char*)(sig), 8);` Thanks